# Run Two thread in C++ console Application

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am having problem in creating C++ application where am using while loop.

```
int checkIP(const char *IP)
{
    WSAData version;        //We need to check the version.
    WORD mkword=MAKEWORD(2,2);
    int what=WSAStartup(mkword,&version);
    if(what!=0){
        std::cout<<"This version is not supported! - \n"<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"Good - Everything fine!\n"<<std::endl;
    }

    SOCKET u_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(u_sock==INVALID_SOCKET)
        std::cout<<"Creating socket fail\n";

    else
        std::cout<<"It was okay to create the socket\n";

    //Socket address information
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.90");
    addr.sin_port=htons(80);
    /*==========Addressing finished==========*/

    //Now we connect
    int conn=connect(u_sock,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    return conn;
}
```

this is the function where I am checking the ip.
i want to run this function in parallel. Like

```
void start(const char* ip)
{
    while(checkIP == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
       try to connect the ip...
   }
}
```

in my main program i want to run this start function but i dont want to wait for the response for this start function... i need that this function should b called and doing its work parallely and the program goes farword like...

```
int Ipcheck = checkIP("192.168.10.90");
    if(Ipcheck == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        ofstream _Log;
        _Log.open ("Log.txt",std::ios_base::app);
        _Log << "Unable to connect to "<<IP<<endl;
        _Log.close();
        start();
        BSTR bstrr = SysAllocString(L"Error");
        return bstrr;
    }
```

like in this code the system calls the start function but i want that it jst call the function and do every thing in backhand and compiler goes on next statement BSTR immediately return the value...
please help  me to do this... sorry for my bad English... kindly give the sample code how to run that while loop event in backhand or parallely...

Comment: Do you know how to create threads at all? Have you done it before? Do you want to use the [Windows system calls to create the thread(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or do you want to use the [threading system in the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)?

Comment: Oh, unrelated to your problem, but you should not call [`WSAStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) more than once, at least not without calling [`WSACleanup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in between.

Comment: In short, use std::async

Answer (score 0):

To create Threads, look at std::thread

Also look at the documentation that's always really helpful
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/540912/Cplusplus-Threads-Make-your-multitasking-life-e

Read through this, help you understand how to safely create threads, stop/avoid data races and locking threads.
Threads are great things, speed up processing, having updates etc running behind the UI while other things are running.

If you need anymore message me on here :) 
Jake

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::thread` could be one solution.  Howere what you really want to do is to run your function asynchronously:  you call the function and do something else while you're waiting until you really need the return value.

For this,  [**`std::async`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/) is exactly what you need !  Here a [little tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/17/cpp-11-async-tutorial/) on this topic.

**Example 1:** function with no return value

```
    future<void> myvres = async(launch::async, start);  // launch function 
    DoSomethingElse(); 
    ... 
    myvres.get();     // here, make sure that start() finished.
```

Interestingly, if `start()` would raises an exception, it would be delayed to this moment you do the get().

**Example 2:** function with return value

```
    future<int> Ipcheck = async(launch::async, checkIP, "192.168.10.90");
    DoSomethingElse(); 
    ... 
    if (Ipcheck.get() == SOCKET_ERROR)   
       ...
```

However, if you're looking for multithreading, only because you don't want to get delayed by socket operations, then thre is a much simpler solution, namely just using your sockets asynchronously.  Here [an example](http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_6.shtm).